# Move sheets from one workbook to another in a loop

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

```
import pandas as pd
xl_dict = {}
sheetname_list = ['2018', '2019', '2020']
#i am able to get the sheets from here
for sheet in sheetname_list:
    xl_dict[sheet] = pd.read_excel('Mvvvv Ds.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
    print(xl_dict[sheet].title)
```

Not able to add sheets in this file,I want to add to add these three sheets in this file.

```
path2 = '2020-01-29.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the [Excel Writer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html). Something like the following may work then,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path2)
[xl_dict[sheetname_list[x]].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname_list[x]) for x in range(len(sheetname_list))]
writer.save()
```

Comment: Try the above now, the xl_dict has to be called through keys not index which is why it was giving an error. Should work now.

Comment: import pandas as pd
xl_dict = {}
sheetname_list = ['2018', '2019', '2020']
path2="A.xlsx"
#i am able to get the sheets from here
for sheet in sheetname_list:
    xl_dict[sheet] = pd.read_excel('Mvv.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path2)
    [xl_dict[sheetname_list[x]].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname_list[x]) for x in range(len(sheetname_list))]
    writer.save()

Comment: it tried this above code i am getting error  KeyError: '2019'